# Как узнать количество задач в очереди

Tags: php, yii2

Для системы очередей использую данное [расширение](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue) .
На сайте стоит Redis движок.

С консоли можно вызывать `yii queue/info` и получить количество элементов в очереди. 
А как получить количество элементов очереди через php?

Comment: Любопытно, а зачем? В каких кейсах имеет смысл использовать кол-во заданий в очереди?

Answer (score 1):

Реализация консольной команды `yii queue/info` выглядит так:

```
public function run()
{
    $prefix = $this->queue->channel;
    $waiting = $this->queue->redis->llen("$prefix.waiting");
    $delayed = $this->queue->redis->zcount("$prefix.delayed", '-inf', '+inf');
    $reserved = $this->queue->redis->zcount("$prefix.reserved", '-inf', '+inf');
    $total = $this->queue->redis->get("$prefix.message_id");
    $done = $total - $waiting - $delayed - $reserved;
    ...
```

Сделайте в коде тоже самое